# Operation not supported: Expense with BillableStatus should have CustomerRef for AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail Line in Purchase

Tags: java, php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I have attempted to submit a Purchase as Check to QBD using PHP SDK with the below XML request content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Purchase xmlns:ns0="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" domain="QB">
  <ns0:TxnDate>2014-02-21</ns0:TxnDate>
  <ns0:PrivateNote>Test for QBD Purchase Check</ns0:PrivateNote>
  <ns0:Line>
    <ns0:Description>E1</ns0:Description>
    <ns0:Amount>10.00</ns0:Amount>
    <ns0:DetailType>AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail</ns0:DetailType>
    <ns0:AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
      <ns0:ClassRef name="Coffee and tea">QB:8</ns0:ClassRef>
      <ns0:AccountRef name="Computer and Internet Expenses">QB:10</ns0:AccountRef>
      <ns0:BillableStatus>NotBillable</ns0:BillableStatus>
      <ns0:TaxCodeRef>NON</ns0:TaxCodeRef>
    </ns0:AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
  </ns0:Line>
  <ns0:Line>
    <ns0:Description>E2</ns0:Description>
    <ns0:Amount>15.00</ns0:Amount>
    <ns0:DetailType>AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail</ns0:DetailType>
    <ns0:AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
      <ns0:CustomerRef name="Arnold Schwarzenegger">QB:3</ns0:CustomerRef>
      <ns0:ClassRef name="Alcoholic beverages">QB:2</ns0:ClassRef>
      <ns0:AccountRef name="Computer and Internet Expenses">QB:10</ns0:AccountRef>
      <ns0:BillableStatus>NotBillable</ns0:BillableStatus>
      <ns0:TaxCodeRef>NON</ns0:TaxCodeRef>
    </ns0:AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
  </ns0:Line>
  <ns0:AccountRef name="My Bank Account">QB:30</ns0:AccountRef>
  <ns0:PaymentType>Check</ns0:PaymentType>
  <ns0:EntityRef name="Herry Pilor">QB:9</ns0:EntityRef>
  <ns0:TotalAmt>25.00</ns0:TotalAmt>
</ns0:Purchase>
```

Since both lines have been marked BillableStatus=NotBillable, however, the first line comes without CustomerRef.

Submit that content should get this response message:

```
http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-02-21T09:04:42.972Z">Operation failed with errors:
Operation not supported: Expense with BillableStatus should have CustomerRef for AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail Line in Purchase </Message></Error></Fault></IntuitResponse>
```

So the question is that why it requires Customer when BillableStatus=NotBillable?

But in the previous Java API version, there was no Customer expected when NotBillable

Please advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

BillableStatus must be excluded from the request if CustomerRef is not specified.  This is a known issue.

Comment: Ohh..so when will it be fixed?

Comment: We do not have a fix date.  You will need to work around the issue by omitting the CustomerRef for NonBillable lines.