# QuickBooks Target is not reimbursable creating a check

Tags: quickbooks

VB.2010, QBFC12, Windows 7, QuickBooks 2010 Premier and Enterprise 14

When trying to create a check for expense accounts with non-billable and a customer name we get a error from QuickBooks 
Status: Code = 3210, Message = The "billable status" field has an invalid value "NotBillable".  QuickBooks error message: Target is not reimbursable., Severity = Error

It seems that it depends upon the account.  But every account we try is defined the same in QB.  All Expense accounts and the name. Nothing else is defined in the Edit Account.

What does this error really mean?
What is the 'target'?
How can I get it to create the Check with it marked Non-billable?

It is really strange.  It seems that it can depend on which account even thought they are all defined the same.

Can any shed some light on this?

Comment: Check the following
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985486/operation-not-supported-expense-with-billablestatus-should-have-customerref-for